# Different outputs

Tags: c, post-increment

Why does the first code give a different output from the second code, even though they intend to do the same thing?

```
while(s[i++]==t[j++]);

while(s[i]==t[j])
        {
            i++;
            j++;
        }
```

Comment: The code given does not produce any output at all.

Comment: You should always specify what you expected to happen, what you observed happening instead, and your thoughts, if any on why that is. In this you only say the output differs, but you don't mention which output you mean, what you expected, nor what actually happened.

Comment: The questions has a bad title, unclear wording, incomplete code snippet, so it'd be worth a downvote.

Comment: I got my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Abhishek if Alok Singhal's answer is what you were looking for you should accept it.

Answer (score 6):

The first code increments `i` and `j` even when `s[i] != t[j]`, while the second doesn't.

For example, with:

```
char s[] = "hello";
char t[] = "world";
int i = 0, j = 0;
```

The first code will have both `i` and `j` equal to `1` after the loop, but the second code will have `i` and `j` equal to `0`.

Comment: Oh! Ok! Thank you so much. I thought that the first one would increment only if they are equal..